# Recommended MySQL data model for similar class objects

Tags: mysql, datamodel

We will be creating a MySQL database to reflect the following PHP classes:

- Content
- Article extends Content
- Post extends Content
- ...

There will be models associated with Content, like Comment, Ignore etc..

The question here is which data model to use.

1) One table per model

2) One large content table (with all class properties as columns), plus single tables for the other models. I believe it's called single table inheritance.

3) A large content table with the common fields, or only the fields we commonly search on (indexes), plus a large content-data table, with the rest of the properties.

4) Another way?

We want to be able to query against the Content, and get recent, location-based or somehow filtered content, regardless of which content type (subclass) it is. Therefore solution 1 is probably out of the question.

This system should be quick and scalable. What is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Personally, I usually go with option 2, since option 3 is reminiscent of EAV, which many top developers consider an anti-pattern.

Comment: You could simply view WordPress schema and copy that.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this topic that you may find helpful: http://jasonswett.net/blog/composition-a-better-alternative-to-orm-inheritance/

First, I'd like to recommend that you call your table `content_item` or something instead of `content`. The reason for this is I believe the table name should match the name of the thing it represents. See [this other blog post of mine](http://jasonswett.net/blog/a-good-name-for-a-database-table-that-stores-news/) for details on that.

So you might have a table called `content_item`, a table called `article` and a table called `post`. `content_item` would have columns like `title`, `slug`, etc - everything that every content item will have, whether it be a post, article or something else. Then `article` would have a `content_item_id` and then anything else that's specific to articles, but *only* what's specific to articles. For each article, you'd have a `content_item` record, then an `article` record that's attached to that `content_item` record.

This would give you the ability to query `content_item` and get results that include all content types.

I've implemented this kind of solution in the past with good success. (I've also tried different approaches and didn't like them as much.)

Comment: I agree on the naming for content_item.

Comment: How would you query this kind of db, if say, you want the 100 most recent content items? The issue here is that you wish to join over different tables, depending on type of content_item (article, post, etc.).

Comment: `SELECT * FROM content_item JOIN article ON article.content_item_id = content_item.id JOIN post ON post.content_item_id = content_item.id ORDER BY content_item.id DESC LIMIT 100`

Answer (score 0):

If they are sufficiently similar objects, i would use option 3... A la drupals node concept or the current wordPress idea of a 'post'

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this perhaps.  Your needs for post vs. articles extending content may differ, but instead of a 1..many relationship from content -> post (or article), why not add flexibility to mix/match content within any.  If you don't need/desire that, then omit the article_content and post_content tables and simply add a foreign key content_id INT NOT NULL to each of the post and article tables respectively..

---

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NULL, body TEXT, published DATETIME NOT NULL, updated DATETIME NULL, owner_id INT DEFAULT '0', status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1', PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX idx_content_status (status));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, excerpt VARCHAR(255) NULL, url_slug VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, author_id INT NOT NULL, published DATETIME NOT NULL, updated DATETIME NULL, status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1', sort_order INT DEFAULT '1', PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE INDEX idx_article_slug(url_slug), INDEX idx_article_search(title, published, status, sort_order));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, comment VARCHAR(128) NULL, author_id INT NOT NULL, published DATETIME NOT NULL, updated DATETIME NULL, status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1', PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, tag VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_content (article_id INT NOT NULL, content_id INT NOT NULL, status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1', sort_order INT DEFAULT '1', INDEX idx_article_content_search(article_id, content_id, status, sort_order));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_content (post_id INT NOT NULL, content_id INT NOT NULL, status TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '1', sort_order INT DEFAULT '1', INDEX idx_post_content_search(post_id, content_id, status, sort_order));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_tags (article_id INT NOT NULL, tag_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX idx_article_tag_search(article_id, tag_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_tags (post_id INT NOT NULL, tag_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX idx_post_tag_search(post_id, tag_id));

Comment: How would you query this kind of db, if say, you want the 100 most recent content items? The issue here is that you wish to join over different tables, depending on type of content_item (article, post, etc.).